# Laravel can't get the values from Vue-multiselect

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, multi-select, vue-multiselect

I am using [Vue-multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/) with Laravel.

I am using the multiselect component in my form to let the user select multiple countries. The component works fine but when I submit the form and I `dd()` it, it shows `[object Object]`.

I can't get the value of the multiselect component. I have found similar questions but none of them worked for me.

Here is my code:

**The ExampleComponent.vue file:**

```
<template slot-scope="{ option }">
<div>

<label class="typo__label">Restricted country</label>
<multiselect
          v-model="internalValue"
          tag-placeholder="Add restricted country"
          placeholder="Search or add a country"
          label="name"
          name="selectedcountries[]"
          :options="options"
          :multiple="true"
          track-by="name"
          :taggable="true"
          @tag="addTag"
          >
</multiselect>

<pre class="language-json"><code>{{ internalValue  }}</code></pre>

</div>
</template>

<script>
 import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'

  // register globally
  Vue.component('multiselect', Multiselect)

  export default {

  components: {
  Multiselect
  },
   props: ['value'],
   data () {
   return {
   internalValue: this.value,
   options: [
    { name: 'Hungary' },
    { name: 'USA' },
    { name: 'China' }
     ]
   }
 },
watch: {
internalValue(v){
this.$emit('input', v);
}
},
methods: {
addTag (newTag) {
  const tag = {
    name: newTag,
    code: newTag.substring(0, 2) + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000))
  }
  this.options.push(tag)
  this.value.push(tag)
  }
 },

 }
 </script>
```

**Here is my register form:**

```
<div id="select">
  <example-component v-model="selectedValue"></example-component>
  <input type="hidden" name="countriespost" :value="selectedValue">
 </div>
 
<script>
   const select = new Vue({
      el: '#select',
      data: {
         selectedValue: null
           },
         });
</script>
```

When I submit the form, the `countriespost` shows me me this: `[object Object]` instead of the actual value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are providing an array of objects as `options` property:

```
options: [
  { name: 'Hungary' },
  { name: 'USA' },
  { name: 'China' }
]
```

so the value emited on `input` is an object.
Try to change the options to following:

```
options: [ 'Hungary', 'USA', 'China' ]
```

Comment: Thanks this will do for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an array of objects to the `:options` prop of the multiselect component, you should submit the form with javascript so you can extract the object ids or whatever you need on the backend and then send them through. 
Add a method like this:

```
submit: function() {
  let data = {
    objectIds: _.map(this.selectedOptions, option => option.id), //lodash library used here
    // whatever other data you need
  }
  axios.post('/form-submit-url', data).then(r =>  {
    console.log(r);
  });
}
```

Then trigger it with a `@click.stop` event on your submit button.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it makes sense now for me.